# Using complex SQL queries in conditional if/else statements

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, exists

I'm trying to set up some SQL test queries to document whether the tests pass or fail in a SQL table. These test queries are run on several separate databases. Here is an example using a basic query (inside the IF statement):

```
DECLARE @dbname NVARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
WHERE name LIKE '%JMPTIPR%'

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

SET @query = CAST('
DECLARE @testStatus NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @version NCHAR(10);
DECLARE @testid INT;
DECLARE @repid INT;

SELECT @name = Column1 from [' +@dbname+ '].dbo.Table1
where Column1 = ''File Name''
SELECT @version = attributedata from [' +@dbname+ '].dbo.Table1 
where Column1 = ''Version Number''
SELECT @testid = COALESCE(MAX(TestNum), 0) FROM [Database1].dbo.Table2;
SELECT @repid = RepNum FROM [Database1].dbo.Table2 
WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM [Database1].dbo.Table2)

IF (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [' +@dbname+ '].dbo.Table1
    WHERE [' +@dbname+ '].dbo.Table1.Column1 LIKE ''%execution%''
) IS NOT NULL
    SET @testStatus = ''Test Passed''
ELSE
    SET @testStatus = ''Test Failed''

INSERT INTO [Database1].dbo.Table3 (FileName, Version, Result, Date, TestNum, RepNum)
VALUES (@name, @version, @testStatus, GETDATE(), @testid, @repid)'
AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

EXECUTE (@query)

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname

END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

The problem is that I have several much more complicated queries that I want to do the same thing with. I have an expected result that should return if everything went according to plan and an expected result if something broke. So here's an example of one of the more complex queries that I want to include:
(Worth noting, that I don't want anyone to simply answer this question by 'fixing' the query. I have too many to put up here for someone to fix and I'd rather learn how to do it myself.)

```
SELECT Table1.Column1, Table2.Column2, Table3.Column3,
  Table3.Column4, Table3.Column5, Table3.Column6,
  Table3.Column7
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN
  Table3 ON Table3.Column8 = Table2.id INNER JOIN
  Table1 ON Table2.Column9 = Table1.id
WHERE (Table3.Column5 = -1 AND Table3.Column7 > 0) OR
  (Table3.Column5 = -1 AND Table3.Column6 > 0) OR
  (Table3.Column5 > Table3.Column6 AND Table3.Column6 > 0) OR
  (Table3.Column6 > Table3.Column7 AND Table3.Column7 > 0)
```

When I slap in this query into my if statement (and change the if condition to `IS NOT NULL`), I get the error message:

```
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

To me it seems like the ultimate issue is that I don't have an advanced enough understanding of SQL to make these work.

**EDIT:** I see several comments saying that because I didn't show the code that isn't working, you can't fix it. I am assuming that you mean that the example code I provided isn't specific enough.

However, that is missing the point of my question. I don't want you to fix that particular code. My question was about the original If/Else code not being able to handle certain, more complex SQL queries (like ones that bring back a full table).

To perhaps give some more context to the example code that I did provide, it is a query that will either bring back nothing (the "Test Passed" condition) or it will bring back a table with multiple rows and columns (the "Test Failed" condition). I was asking about how to take the original query that I have that works for simple queries and adapt it to queries that will not be able to be simply "Counted" or other simple functions.

Comment: like the error says, you have a subquery that's returning MULTIPLE fields, in a context where only one field is allowed. e.g. `select ... where foo = (select field1, field2 from ....)`. what value should `foo` be compared against? `field1`? or `field2`? hence the error - you need to eliminate the ambiguity

Comment: I understand your point of view but WE CAN'T FIX AN SQL STATEMENT IF YOU DON'T GIVE US THE CODE FOR THE SQL STATEMENT.   It is nice that you gave us the error code ... but PLEASE give us the actual SQL that has an error.

Comment: Also, you probably just need to read about how `EXISTS()` works

Comment: The comment by @MarcB is the answer.

Comment: Caution: don't do this: `'[' + @dbname + ']'`, do this: `+ QUOTENAME(DB_NAME(DB_ID(@dbname))) +` Why? (1) `QUOTENAME()` properly escapes garbage with `[` and `]` characters, and (2) wrapping `DB_NAME()/DB_ID()` ensures that the passed database name is actually valid.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the name comes from sys.databases

Comment: you do not a count(*) of zero is not null ?

Comment: One *small* comment: `IF (SELECT COUNT(*) ... without HAVING ) IS NOT NULL` will always return true -> `test passed` because COUNT(*) returns 0 or more.

Comment: @Paparazzi So? Try `CREATE DATABASE "foo]bar";` - that can still break without `QUOTENAME()`. And still, if anyone learns from this code or copies it elsewhere, it may be thought to be ok to use `'[' + @dbname + ']'` in general, including cases where `@dbname` is provided as user input, and there are not-so-obvious dangers associated with that.

Comment: In reference to all comments, see the edit that I made on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since Marc doesn't seem interested in following through, here is the answer to your question.

The "complexity" of your query has no bearing on the issue.   You got the error for one reason, and you could have gotten the same error from a very simple query as well.

This query works (as you noted):

```
IF (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [' +@dbname+ '].dbo.Table1
    WHERE [' +@dbname+ '].dbo.Table1.Column1 LIKE ''%execution%''
) IS NOT NULL
...
```

The reason this query works is because the subquery in the IF() returns a single value.  The count.  One row, one column.   That one value can be tested to see if it is NULL, so there is no problem.

This query would not work:

```
IF (
    SELECT Column1, Column2
    FROM [' +@dbname+ '].dbo.Table1
    WHERE [' +@dbname+ '].dbo.Table1.Column1 LIKE ''%execution%''
) IS NOT NULL
...
```

The only reason it does not work is that the subquery in the IF() returns more than one column, so the results of this query CANNOT be compared to NULL.  Maybe in your mind there is some way you think it might be done (either column is NULL, both columns are NULL, etc.), but I assure you it cannot. The SQL engine does not know how to compare a resultset (multiple columns) to NULL.   It is not the way SQL Server works.   It can only compare a single, scalar value to NULL.

That is why you got the error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Your "complex" query has more than one column (expression) in the select list.  And that is the only reason.  No matter how complex your query is, if it only returns one column, you can use it in your IF() statement with no problem.

Looking at your edit, if you only need to test whether your complex query returns rows or not, then you can just replace the column list with a COUNT(*) like you did in the query that works.

Answer (score -1):

I can't speak to the code you didn't show us but I can point out a better way to do the code you did show.  Maybe it will fix the problem you have when you apply it to the mystery code:

This

```
IF (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [' +@dbname+ '].dbo.Table1
    WHERE [' +@dbname+ '].dbo.Table1.Column1 LIKE ''%execution%'' 
) IS NOT NULL
  SET @testStatus = ''Test Passed''
ELSE
 SET @testStatus = ''Test Failed''
```

Is the same as

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [' +@dbname+ '].dbo.Table1
    WHERE [' +@dbname+ '].dbo.Table1.Column1 LIKE ''%execution%'')
  SET @testStatus = ''Test Passed''
ELSE
  SET @testStatus = ''Test Failed''
```

Comment: Well, not the same.  count(*) of zero is still not null.   But probably what the OP intends to to.

Comment: @Paparazzi you can get count(*) to return 0?

Comment: So if the count is zero what do you think would be returned?

Comment: @Paparazzi nothing... the where will filter all rows and no results are returned.

Comment: Really so if I ask for count of students with an age < 7 and there are none  I should get no result rather than zero.

Comment: Give this a try select count(*) from [anyValidTable] where 1 = 0

Comment: No, `COUNT(*)` will never filter out all rows and return no results. It will either return 0 or a non-zero integer. Neither of which will ever be NULL, so with the code you suggested in the first example, it is not logically possible to ever print `'Test failed'`. As a result, "Is the same as" is also incorrect - the `EXISTS` method works as you suggest, but checking for a count to be null will not. Did you try it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - you make a good point -- I didn't try since I always use EXISTS() in cases like this and surround a count with with a coalesce to 0

Comment: In reference to all comments, see the edit that I made on the question.

Comment: @David - my answer is still correct with your update -- use `EXISTS()`  if there is a reason you can't use this to solve you problem you need to give an example.